# How much memory does the NSNotificationCenter uses

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsnotificationcenter

What is the usage of memory/processing that I'll have when use one:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismissKeyboard) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Or:

```
NSNotificationCenter * notificationCenter = 
[notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismissKeyboard) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

*PS: I think of to use `NSNotificationCenter` to three different things. So my curiosity*

Comment: You want to know how much memory your application is using when you add observers to the Notification Center?

Comment: Yes. If the Notification Center will use a lot of my hardware

Comment: I am sure that the memory and processor time consumption will be far less than when you load an image from resources. This is not the thing you should worry about.

Comment: It's not enough to worry about.  If you're sufficiently OCD that you *must* know, devise a way to measure it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Your question is a little unclear. If you mean "how much time does it take to call `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`?", don't worry about that. It's trivial. Usually people unload `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` into a variable to save typing. I usually call the variable `nc` because it's so long. The rest of this answer has to do with `NSNotification` performance which may not be what you were asking.*

Cocoa does not generally make promises about these things. You can't rely on the implementation details, and unfortunately, `CFNotificationCenter` is not part of the open source version of Core Foundation, so you can't poke around and see how it's currently implemented.

But experience suggests (based on performance tuning I had to do a few years ago) that it's implemented as an array of observations. So it stores the observer, the selector, the name, and the object, which requires about 4x(pointersize) memory plus probably a ObjC structure overhead. So maybe 20-odd bytes or the like on a 64-bit platform.

`addObserver` and `removeObserver` were roughly equivalent to the cost of adding or removing an entry to an `NSMutableArray` (in particular, `removeObserver` is O(n) on the total number of observations registered with the center). Posting a notification is O(n) on the total number of observations registered with the center. (Again, this is based on reverse engineering; it could change over time, but I seriously doubt it. I'm sure this is very stable code by now.)

That means that `NSNotification` does not scale well to thousands of observations. This is not to suggest that you should "avoid `NSNotification` for performance reasons." (I hate when people say things like that without actually verifying it for their situation.) It just means that you need to be thoughtful before creating many hundreds or thousands of notifications in a system. That's what KVO is specifically designed for.

For your particular example, this is exactly what `NSNotification` is designed for, so it's what you should use.

Comment: Thanks so much @Rob Napier you clarify exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C is [dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) language. Which mean that message [notification is at the core of Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Notification.html). You don't meet worry about how much memory is used.  Just pay attention to fact that when you add an Observer, to make sure you remove them.